# WPF Setter Property not picking up bindings from a StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a bunch of ListBoxItems, and want to be able to remove one when right-clicking it.  So I have a context-menu declared as a static resource, and that resource is being used as one of the Setter Properties for the ListBoxItem style:

```
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ClearFilt">
        <MenuItem Header="Remove Item from Filter View" Command="{Binding}" CommandParameter="{Binding vfm_string}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Clear Filter" Command="{Binding}" CommandParameter="Clear"/>
    </ContextMenu>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{ StaticResource ClearFilt}"/>
```

With this code, the menu appears just fine when I right click the ListBoxItem:

[image]

However, clicking on each menu item ("Remove Item from Filter View" and "Clear Filter") does not call the corresponding Execute function.  How can I get the Setter Property to keep the data context? i.e. why isn't it triggering the underlying Command object when I click on the menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the setter properties do not have visibility into the data context. Creating a proxy binding class implementing Freezable will link the property to the data context.  Per Thomas Levesque's blog:

http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/